# CORS Headers Not Present in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am attempting to make an ajax call to a remote server, this is only for development purposes. I have CORS setup on my server, and as a result my response when requesting the resource through the browser looks like this.

[image: Browser Request]

As you can see the CORS headers are present, however my JavaScript request gets an error.

[image]

[image]

I am confused as to why my CORS headers are not present in the JavaScript request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as to why my CORS headers are not present in the JavaScript request.

They are never present in the *request*. CORS headers are *response* headers. (Well, some CORS headers are request headers, `Origin` for example, and that is in the request headers you listed).

> The response had HTTP status code 401

Presumably your server side code is only going to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header when it makes a 200 OK response.

Since the request was missing the cookie, it rejected it as unauthorised.

Cross-origin XHR requests need to set [`withCredentials`](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute) to `true` in order for the browser to send or accept Cookies.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, sorry for the confusion there at the end, the lunch train was leaving out the door and I was typing as fast as I could. Everything works!